# Is there a function that is surjective if and only if it is injective?

Tags: functions

Apparently there are some but I can't think of any.

Comment: $f(x) = x$ is a function which is injective and surjective, and hence "injective iff surjective". "f(x) = 1" is neither injective nor surjective, and hence "injective iff surjective". Usually statements like your title's refer to an entire class of functions, rather than a single one. Did you mean something else?

Comment: This is true of functions from a finite set to itself, but it's a bit unclear what you mean by asking this about "a function".  Any particular function either is surjective or not, and similarly is injective or not.

Comment: Is $f(x)=x$ injective by virtue of being surjective? I think that's what I'm trying to get at but I don't know how to articulate it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes; a linear map between vector spaces of the same finite dimension is injective iff it is surjective because of the rank-nullity theorem.

Edit: 
 For completeness, as lhf and others have pointed out, a map from a finite set to a set of the same size is injective iff it is surjective.

Comment: Right; maybe I can include it for completeness.

Comment: You're right. Will edit.

Comment: You should really say "_finite-dimensional_ vector spaces of the same dimension".

Comment: But how is this different from "vector spaces of the same finite dimension"?

Comment: That's not what your first version said! You should know, you wrote it.